# Remove extra whitespaces from extracted PDF text

Tags: php, pdf

I have extracted the text from a PDF file and some of the text has extra whitespaces between words.

> Your water a n d wastewater s t a t e m e n t

I wrote a function to remove the extra spaces from the text above.

```
function removeExtraWhitespace($val) {
    $nval = "";

    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($val); $i++) {
        if($val[$i] != " ") {
            $nval .= $val[$i];
        }
        else if((isset($val[$i-2]) && $val[$i-2] != " ") || (isset($val[$i+2]) && $val[$i+2] != " ")) {
            $nval .= $val[$i];
        }
    }
    return $nval;
}
```

Which will output:

> Your water and wastewater statement

I know that this function will not work in all circumstances though. If the text has a valid 1 letter word, like 'a', then it will fail, or if only part of a word has extra spaces.

> I n e e d to remove whitespaces f r o m a string

When putting the above text in to my function it will output:

> Ineed to remove whitespaces froma string

Is there a way to make a function that will work on all possible text?

Comment: in this string no unique identification to remove the white space. if first alphabet is capital of each word then it's possible

Comment: I would think of passing text passages like sentence by sentence to an autocorrection API service. Maybe there is a google assistant API or sth. like that.

Comment: Maybe it's worth to take some more effort as well: I guess, the PDF looks okay concerning your text examples? So maybe your parsing lib or whatever you use is just not good enough or must be used another way?

Comment: @iquellis I have tried several ways of extracting the text from the PDFs. The example text came from using ebook-convert, which so far has produced the best results for me to parse.

Comment: @Gary: Good, just wanted to be sure, that you tried more than one way... PDFs simpy suck big time...

Comment: Mission imposible. "In general - `a n a l p h a b e t` is a good thing".
Should be translated to - "In general - `an alphabet` is a good thing". Or "In general - `analphabet` is a good thing" ?

Comment: I suggest trying to use "pdftotext" which comes with XPDF (opensource). Maybe like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9286036/how-to-extract-texts-from-pdfs-using-xpdf

Comment: The correct answer to this question is "no", unless you have very specific paramaters in terms of what text you expect to be inside the PDF, or you are Google. You should instead focus on extracting it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Spelling correction is hard work. I think you should use online spelling correction websites. You can do something like this:

```
function curl($post)
{
    $user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; tr; rv:1.9.0.6) Gecko/2009011913 Firefox/3.0.6';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://orthographe.reverso.net/RISpellerWS/RestSpeller.svc/v1/CheckSpellingAsXml/language=eng?outputFormat=json&doReplacements=false&interfLang=en&dictionary=both&spellOrigin=interactive&includeSpellCheckUnits=true&includeExtraInfo=true&isStandaloneSpeller=true');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Created: 01/01/0001 00:00:00',
        'Referer: http://www.reverso.net/spell-checker/english-spelling-grammar/',
        'Username: OnlineSpellerWS'
    ));
    $icerik = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $icerik;
}


$response   = json_decode(curl('Ineed to remove whitespaces froma string'));

var_dump($response->AutoCorrectedText);
```

It is just for idea. I am sure there are spelling correction websites which provide API.